# ASP.NET Authentication Troubleshooting

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, webserver

I have a fairly complex web app that was built (by a contractor) to use integrated authentication.  As part of the authentication process, a `GetNetworkID()` function is used that looks like this:

```
private string GetNetworkID()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1];
}
```

When I run this on my development box, the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` value is 
*myNetwork\\myUserID*, so the above funciton returns my User ID, as intended, and the authenticaiton process works just fine.

But when I run this on my web server, I get an *Index was outside the bounds of the array* error thrown by the return statement in the `GetNetworkID()` function.

I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot this and how to figure out if it's an IIS configuration issue (my web server is a Windows Server 2008 box running IIS 7), or something else.

If I hard-code my User ID as the return value for the `GetNetworkID()` function, it works on the web server, but I don't have any great ideas about how to debug on the web server to determine what the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` return value is that's causing the array index error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this something you can debug or log on your machine?  If, for example, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is something unexpected, like ASPNET, then it may be an IIS configuration issue on your box.

Comment: Thanks David--like I say, it works on my machine (and I'm using VS & Cassini, so I don't really have any IIS config to do).  I have IIS on the server, of course, but it has the most generic of out-of-the-box settings, and my attempts to tweak the authentication at that end have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Edit: I should mention that I've tried the Response.Write method of troubleshooting a number of different ways.  It's a bit convoluted because there are a number of other steps involved in the authentication code, but it looks like it's returning my name ("Joe Blow") instead of my User ID.  So, yeah, maybe I just answered my own question there...  Let me work on that a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS runs as the IIS Service Account, so Current.User.Identity is likely going to be the name of the IIS Account.

For completeness sake, you should check for '\' either with a Find() or by calling split, and checking the length of the resultant array. If the length is 1, that means the id isn't in the form of domain\username.

In general, if you want to debug, you can write any value to the HTTP Response stream like so:

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
```

Another method is to setup an ASP page variable, and set the page variable to the value you'd like to inspect. You can display the variable value either through ASP code, or through Javascript.

Comment: Okay, so Alan wins the prize, and I have self-administered a dope-slap for my lack of insight.  As it turns out, on my local machine the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is MyNetwork\\MyUserID.  On the Server the value is "Joe Blow".  Don't know why; don't know how I'm going to deal with that, but that's what's throwing the array index error.  Thank you all for your time and not calling me out for the knucklehead that I am.

Comment: Got it fixed, and it was a simple setting.  As it turns out, I was only looking at IIS authentication methods for the app directory, trying different settings with no success.  The “Joe Blow” return value was happening with Anonymous authentication, causing the array index exception.  All other authenticaion methods gave me a 401 response.  Turns out that Windows Authentication at the server level was disabled and set to give the user a 401 response.  Once I enabled Windows Authentication at the server level, it worked like a champ--no array index exception and successful authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing an IIS setting.

Try in IIS:
Website (right click) | Properties | Directory Security (tab)

Click "Edit..."

Then select "Integrated Windows Authentication"

Comment: And turn off the other forms of authentication.

Comment: Thanks Destructr...  Not sure if I trust you with a user name like that.  :)  
Seriously though, I did muck with the directory security and tried all combinations of authentication settings in IIS.  No luck.  I think Alan's got me going in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Destructr, the process to enable WIA is a bit different in IIS 7, but this is what essentially fixed my problem.  WIA was disabled at the parent directory level above my app's directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the user that logs into your web applciation on the other server, is not a valid login. And hence a result is not returned on User.Identity.Name.

Like you said, it works when you hardcoded the username.
This means, the user creditials of the PC you are using to login is not permitted on your site. This therefore must be different to the credentials you are hardcoding.

Best bet is to debug on web server (it isn't hard - all you want to return is the User.Identity.Name and you can get the username and deduce logic from there), and verify the contents in your web.config file.

Comment: Thanks for you help, waqasahmed.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan pointed out (and I upvoted him for it) you probably want to add a check on what form the `User.Identity.Name` takes. An updated routine could for example look like this:

```
private string GetNetworkID()
{
    var name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    return name.InStr("\\") > -1 ? name.Split("\\")[1] : name;
}
```

This will return the second part of the login name if a `\` is present, and the full string if not.